# Mysql update using REPLACE and LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I have a record in a table like:

```
aaaa bbbbb_ ccccc_1
```

OR

```
gggg jjjjj_fffff _34
```

Note the white space and underscore and the underscore and whitespace.
Note that the string and number format may be different.

I'd like to select and update these infos in database using single line query.

**What i did so far:**

```
$update = " UPDATE table 
               SET SKU = REPLACE((
                        SELECT  SKU 
                        FROM    table 
                        WHERE   SKU LIKE '%\_ %' OR SKU LIKE '% \_%'
                      ),replace('_ ', ' _'),replace('_', '_'))";
```

**Translated:**
Update table SKU = replace from select case 1 (_ ) or case 2 ( _) with simple _

**Question:**
This query fails... why?

**EDIT 1:**

[Here](https://www.tghfashion.com/GDev/depozit_modify_sku.php)'s a link where you can see all records that contain " _" OR "_ " in it.
I'm using this:

```
SELECT SKU FROM table WHERE SKU LIKE '%\_ %' OR SKU LIKE '% \_%'
```

Using Tim's suggestion, the query above doesnt list 700+ records, it shows 530 instead. So the Tim's query worked for few but not for all

Comment: Really confusing query here.  It seems like your WHERE condiiton should be on the parent query, not the sub query and why are you calling replace the 2nd and 3rd time?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the actual data.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did that -> Edit 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just nest two calls to `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE table
SET SKU = REPLACE(REPLACE(SKU, '_ ', '_'), ' _', '_')
WHERE SKU REGEXP ' _|_ ';
```

Note that MySQL does not really support any sort of regex replacement, so `REPLACE` is about as good as it gets (though we were able to use `REGEXP` in the `WHERE` clause).

**Edit:**

To *verify* that the update has in fact removed/fixed all the bad data, you may try using the following select query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SKU REGEXP ' _|_ ';
```

Note that this query should return *no* results, because if it does, it means that the update logic was not completely correct.

Comment: Nice query! I like the way you wrote it but unfortunatelly... i had 734 records t update... after running the query above i still have 530
And believe me, there are still same records to update

Comment: Then maybe MySQL isn't the best place to be doing such data scrubbing.  I don't think an index would really help here, either.

Comment: Used the Select SKU i wrote above after runned your query and returns me 530 records with " _" or "_ "

Comment: I don't understand how this could be happening.  Which data has the text `or` even to begin with?

Comment: I see... then i'm gonna export an array from select query and make another update after some parseing

Comment: It is set to show these records with " _" OR "_ " inside

Comment: The underscore isnt visible in comments?

Comment: @OzZie [Check this demo](http://rextester.com/WXI39216) which contains samples of the two types of SKUs which appear in your actual data set.  As you can see, the query is correctly picking up on both of them.  So, I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: @OzZie Your `SELECT` statement is wrong.  You should just be doing `SELECT *`, because the replacements have already happened.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: you're right... i'm sorry! :( Accepted answer with many thanks!